# How to optimize results for Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I've looked around, and there are no threads pertaining to a question like this.

I'm using [elasticsearch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch) and I am running into a problem. I'm [querying](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/lucene-query.html) first for the whole string, then using AND, but the results are not accurate. A search for the whole string returns nothing, but a search for `'brian cardeau'` returns 142 results, only two of which are at all relevant. It seems to be `AND`ing the `'brian'` part and finding all result that contain that word. Is there a way around this?

Im using a basic search as,

```
try {
  const response = await client.search({
    q: 'brian cardeau'
  });

  if (response.hits.hits.length === 0) {
     const response2 = await client.search({
         q: 'brian AND cardeau'
     });
  }

  if (response2.hits.hits.length === 0) {
     const response3 = await client.search({
         q: 'brian OR cardeau'
     });
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.trace(error.message)
}
```

Give or take thats the code. It's wrapped in a promise all and uses array destructuring, but thats the gist of the logic, I dont have the code in front of me right now.

Comment: Can you add your mapping and query.

Comment: I dont have the code in front of me right now, but I added the idea of the logic I have, thank you

Comment: can you elaborate the problem? the expected result? i didn't really understand what the problem is

Comment: When I search for 'brian caredeau', im expecting at most 4 results, not 142. How can I optimize the results of this query? I want `brian AND cardeau` and `brian OR caredeau` to be falls backs in the event nothing is found, but i dont want 142 invalid results

Comment: You need to add sample data to your question, for each request can you explain what is an expected result and what is unexpected/unaccurate (and add the concerned documents).